# Why isn't the user #1 able to edit the user details?

Tags: 6, users

I have one site in Drupal 6. When I log in as user #1, and I visit the page at user/[uid]/edit, I am not able to access this page. I get an access denied error.

Can any one please tell me what may be the problem, and the solution?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably a conflict/misconfiguration of some module (or permissions) you have installed on the site and that deals with users or permissions.

Super user (uid: 1) has all privileges, whether or not the admin role exists.

Make a dev version of the site and start disabling modules one by one to find which one caused this.

Which modules do you have installed? Any custom modules? Is there anything in the database/error log?

Answer (score -1):

You have to make sure the the permission " Administer users " is checked for Administrator role in your permission page.

*update* 
[image]

Comment: there is no role like Administrator.

Comment: No role Administrator? do you mean it was removed?

Comment: [Admin role](http://drupal.org/project/adminrole) used to be a contrib module for D6 before it made it into D7 core. He probably doesn't have it installed.

Comment: so whether i need to install it. I dont think, because without installing it, Admin should be accessible to all pages(If not hard coded in code).

Comment: This unfortunately doesn't answer the question.  OP has stated he is using the user 1 credentials - user 1 inherits all permissions.

Comment: Still looking for answer.